# Angular2 routing with lazy modules

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I try to figure out how to configure routing in my application with lazy loaded modules.

For instance I have a lazy module called AnimalsModule, and I want that this module handle 2 routes "/cats" and "/dogs".

In current router api I need to specify common path for all lazy module routes, like: 'animals/dogs' and 'animals/cats'.

```
{
   path: "animals",
   loadChildren: "animals"
}
```

I can specify empty path for AnimalsModule:

```
{
    path: "",
    loadChildren: "animals"
},
{
   path: "foo",
   component: FooComponent
}
```

But in this case AnimalsModule will be unnecessary loaded when user navigates to "/foo" resource.

If I create 'animals/cats' and 'animals/dogs' routes and in the future I want to refactor my code to split AnimalsModule into DogsModule and CatsModule (also lazy), I will have to break my application routes. (same for merge)

How to create routing with lazy module without common path?

Comment: But why dont you just write foo route out of  the animalmodule? If you do so, I dont think then it has anything to do with animalmodule.  And at the end you want to split it so better to define it ouside of the animalmodule.

Comment: "foo" does not have anithing to do with AnimalsModule, but in this example AnimalsModule will be loaded when accessing "foo" route

Answer (score 1):

Routes have a property called `matcher` property [see docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Routes-type-alias.html), where you can provide your own route matching logic, but as in the comment of the question, I'd really either create 2 routes or even separate them into 2 modules (more likely).

Comment: It seems that docs for UrlMatcher [broken](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/UrlMatcher) and I can find any other documentation. I think that separate module only for routing purpose - not a good idea. Module usually represent an separate application feature and there is no unambiguous relationship with routing

Comment: Here's the source of truth for `UrlMatcher` documentation, from source code: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/src/config.ts#L272

Comment: I try but I can't implement matcher for described issue. Also I try to copy defaultUrlMatcher implementation for my lazy module route and I don't receive the same behaviour. I guess that lazy module routes it's a special case for angular router

Comment: Ensure you have latest Angular packages. Currently 2.4.3